# Migrate SQL Server database with instance level logins

Tags: sql-server, migration

Is there a way to migrate database along with all users and logins at the instance and database levels?

I am aware of contained databases and orphan users and solution for that.

I am using SQL Server 2012, 2014, and 2016. I came across another blog that Import Export functionality can be used, but yet have to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this:

sp_help_revlogin

This stored procedure, provided by Microsoft in the link below, will generate a T-SQL script that will copy the logins, their passwords and their corresponding SIDs (or security identification number, which is usually the culprit here).  This is also a great utility when the database has numerous users with various security levels and passwords.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/918992

This scripts out all Instance level logins.
You can use this scripts and re create logins and map them to database in destination server.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

There are some fantastic Powershell scripts located at [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/functions/).

You could use [Copy-SqlDatabase](https://dbatools.io/functions/copy-sqldatabase/) to migrate your databases.

Then, you could take advantage of [Copy-SqlLogin](https://dbatools.io/functions/copy-sqllogin/) by generating the Powershell commands via T-SQL script for the logins you're interested in.

```
select 'Copy-SqlLogin -Source sqlserver -Destination sqlcluster -Logins ' + name + '' from sys.database_principals where type_desc='sql_user'
```

After migration, make sure you take care of orphan users.  You could use something like this:

```
declare @cmd varchar(max)=''
select
    @Cmd=@cmd + 'ALTER USER ' + dp.name + ' WITH LOGIN = ' + dp.name + ';' + char(10)
from
    sys.database_principals dp left join
    master.sys.server_principals sp on
        sp.name=dp.name
where
    dp.type='s' and
    dp.default_schema_name<>dp.name and
    sp.name is not null
order by dp.name
--print @Cmd
exec (@cmd)
```